# I want to remove double quote ("") from a particular column of a table in hive when I query it

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I want to remove double quote ("") from a particular column of a table in hive when I query it.

|Kine|anti "illicit"|reuse|precious|..... When I query the Hive table, I want to remove the double quote in the 2nd column. And for it to be in this form... |Kine|anti illicit|reuse|precious|

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `regexp_replace`:

```
select regexp_replace(landmark , '["]', '') as landmark
```

If you want to remove tab, newline, double-quote and pipe:

```
select regexp_replace(landmark, '["\t\n|]', '') as landmark;
```

Comment: hi @leftjoin... Thanks for the reply. The problem is I already used regexp_replace to handle a pipe function for the same column as follows: regexp_replace(landmark,'(\\|)|(\t)|(\n)','') AS landmark    . The question is how can I use this same regexp_replace on the same column using what you sent considering I already used it to handle an extra a pipe character.

Comment: Many thanks @leftjoin .That works pretty well. Really appreciate.